# PSQL console in PgAdmin IV

Tags: console, psql, pgadmin-4

Can anyone tell me where I can find it (or what's the workaround) ?

In PgAdmin III it is in "Plugins".

I need it in order to \copy.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is yet to be implemented and already in queue.

Feature request: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2341

There is no workaround, You have to execute it manually from terminal/command prompt.

Comment: and until this day ?

Comment: and how about \set height  ??

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in server mode for pgadmin